# Visual Studio on Mac enters debug mode without a breakpoint with an unusual recommendation for ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swashbuckle, visual-studio-mac

I'm using VS for Mac and after I added Swashbuckle, the debugger now halts on the following line in Startup.Cs.

[image]

In order for the ASP.NET Core site to launch, I need to remove the following lines from `Configure()`.  Commenting them out doesn't work.
            //app.UseStaticFiles();

```
        //app.UseSwagger();

        //app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        //{
        //    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "New API");
        //});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be related to the integration of comments based on [this documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio-mac)

The following entry was manually added to the *.config file, and removing it solved the two strange bugs of "commented out code causing execution to stop", and non-commenting of the same.

```
<GenerateDocumentationFile>false</GenerateDocumentationFile>
```